# How to create top menu bar in QT HTML5 project?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT 5.2.1 is there is any way to add top menu bar in QT HTML5 Project?

my main.cpp file is :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "html5applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.showExpanded();
    viewer.loadUrl(QUrl(QLatin1String("http://url-hidden/")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Did you find an way to do this?

Comment: I've asked it for myself and got an answer. So anybody that will come across this post: [The answer can you find here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25002349/1175881)