# QT HTML5 with Menu Bar like real program

Tags: c++, html, qt, menubar

I'm working on an QT HTML5 application and I was wondering how i could add an top menu just like normal program ( with the default `file, tools, help...` options ).

I think that I've to change something in the `html5applicationviewer.cpp`, but I've got 0 knowledge of that ( I'm learning this... )

Even if you could point me a little bit in the right direction, I'm grateful. I've searched around, but found absolutely nothing about this topic ( but maybe i didn't search right... )

If you need more info, please ask.

Comment: you have to make one by using html/css/jquery if you want i will try to make an expemle

Comment: @Youness, an example is not needed for that. I've developed a couple of website's before, so i know how to do that. But i was hoping for an possibility to create an "program" menu....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to add normal "desktop"-style menus to a Qt app is to use `QMainWindow` which has [good support for menus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#creating-menus).

Here's something to get you started. First I created the default HTML5 Qt application with Qt Creator (SDK version 5.2.1). Then I edited the *main.cpp* and added some lines. Result is below, original lines without comment and all added lines with comment.

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QMainWindow> // added
#include <QMenuBar> // added
#include <QMenu> // added
#include <QAction> // added

#include "html5applicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow w; // important, viewer is in stack so w must be before it!

    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;

    w.setCentralWidget(&viewer); // set viewer as the central widget
    QMenu *fileMenu = w.menuBar()->addMenu("&File"); // create file menu
    QAction *exitAction = fileMenu->addAction("&Exit"); // create exit action
    QObject::connect(exitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit())); // make the action do something

    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    //viewer.showExpanded(); // will be shown by main window
    viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("html/index.html"));

    w.show(); // show main window

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! That was indeed what i was looking for... 1 question. Why do you use an asterisk `*` before `fileMenu and exitAction`? ( I'll also Google why you're using it. But maybe will your explanation help me understand the choose in this particular case...

Comment: @Mathlight `*` there means pointer. `QObject`s are almost always used through a pointer, having them as plain value variables (like `w` and `viewer` here) is unusual. You should probably spend some time with C++ basics... :-)

Comment: I'll need indeed more time with the basics :D But thank you for pointing that out for me!